# shopp plugin page and product not found

Tags: wordpress, shopp

In my wordpress I have installed the shopp plugin and added a test product. When I try to view it I get a page not found error. e.g.

```
http://example.com/shop/test-product/
```

the same goes for
     http://example.com.com/shop

I believe I have everything setup properly. I have my pages setup in the Shopp pages admin view. I have not added any page to my pages. Do I need to add one or does the shopp plugin do it for me automatically?

Thank you for any help!!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this question? Do you still need help?

Comment: it could be you need to refresh your permalinks

Comment: Got it. Just needed to buy the license.

Comment: Ehm, no. Shopp should work without buying support. It is free software you can download it from wordpress.org or github.com and use it, change it, extend it anyway you like. If you need help from the Helpdesk or want access to the forum, in other words if you need support, then you buy support. The plugin should work fine out-of-the-box.